# Mount snaps on boot

Tags: snap

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my system now, and we get encouraged to use snaps on the system now. I like the idea of snaps but I think it is annoying that after boot, those snap packages have to be mounted when you start the application. Which takes time.

Now my question is: Would it be possible to mount these snap packages before I have to use them?

For me, I would prefer to have a longer boot time (with mounting the snaps already) then having to wait when you click the application icon.

Thanks in advance

Niels

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is later today assuming all goes well with todays testing).

Answer (score 1):

Mounting does not take a lot of time. What needs time is loading libraries.
All installed snaps are mounted during boot.

You can check directly after login with the `lsblk`-command, don't start any snaps before doing this:

```
~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 156.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
loop1    7:1    0  55.1M  1 loop /snap/wire/132
loop2    7:2    0 160.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop3    7:3    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
loop4    7:4    0 584.8M  1 loop /snap/supertuxkart/370
loop5    7:5    0  93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop6    7:6    0  93.9M  1 loop /snap/core/9066
loop7    7:7    0 125.1M  1 loop /snap/tmnationsforever/28
loop8    7:8    0  54.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop9    7:9    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop10   7:10   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
loop11   7:11   0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop12   7:12   0  72.3M  1 loop /snap/wire/114
loop13   7:13   0 584.8M  1 loop /snap/supertuxkart/341
loop14   7:14   0  54.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/1668
loop15   7:15   0   131M  1 loop /snap/tmnationsforever/32
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   250G  0 part /media/DATA
└─sda2   8:2    0  48.1G  0 part /media/backup
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   308M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0  37.3G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   4.7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb4   8:20   0  38.1G  0 part /
├─sdb5   8:21   0  39.7G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0 811.5G  0 part /media/data
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

You can see that all snaps are mounted already even if you haven't started them.

Alternatively you can use the command `findmnt` which will also show all snaps mounted.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. So now my question is if it is possible to load those libraries before using the application?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a question instead of a comment.