# Can I make snap to preload packages (pycharm) on boot?

Tags: snap, intellij, pycharm

Some packages, like Intellij's PyCharm, etc. take an insanely long time to start for the first time. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229754/411655) which is about the same problem, but asked wrongly, it seems.

Basically, what I would like is snap to perform the "first start" of the snap app for me in the background as the OS boots / I log in so that I wouldn't have to wait literally minutes for the app to start.

Or is there a setting that would utilise all of my processor's cores as it decompresses the package? As I understand this, it's [possibly a problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268292) with the default xz compression for the packages, though it seems unlikely as - as the mentioned issue explains - it wasn't a problem before 2021.x versions. Regardless, subsequent starts are fast, so I want the "first one" done for me in the background.